# Ошибка: undefined variable $connect

Tags: php, mysql

Подключил БД в файле connect.php:

```php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','users');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда хочу получить значение переменной `$connect`, то получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Директория та же? Попробуй `./connect.php`  и покажи что внутри другого файла написано

Comment: <?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','users');

    if (!$connect){
        die('Error connect');
    } - это connect.php